# Is there any other way to retrive data from server side like HTTPWEBREQUEST

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://URL");
objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
objHttpWebRequest.Headers["authentication"] = clsGlobal.AuthKey;
```

this method is goes to Async so I am suffering lots of problem into sorting as well counting item and assing the value.

so my question is is there any another method Like WebClient so that I can access my data.?

Note :

I had tried with WebClient but it will not work.!

it will give me error like this

**The remote server returned an error: NotFound.**

does anyone know why.?

my code like..

```
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
            client.Headers["authentication"] = AEGAPI.clsGlobal.AuthKey; 
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: Why won't it work with `WebClient`? There are VERY good reasons that synchronous requests for a web resource are not supported. What are are the actual problems you're having?

Comment: I am not able to define Headers["authentication"] = clsGlobal.AuthKey;
 that is required to retrieve data.